# Display values of array of objects in Table format in ReactNative

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I am new to React Native. My objective is to display this below array of objects in table format in React Native. I am using DataTable of React-Native-Paper.

```
var accounts=[
        {
            "accNumber": "56456454",
            "accType": "D",
            "productCode": "1454541",
            "availBalance": "987436.46",
          },
        {
            "accNumber": "12424345645",
            "accType": "D",
            "productCode": "154545641",
            "availBalance": "500397.64",
          },
        {
            "accNumber": "4554545664",
            "accType": "D",
            "productCode": "44545",
            "availBalance": "2467.02",
          }
    ]
```

I have tried this but still it is showing an error:

```
 <DataTable>
   <DataTable.Header>
      <DataTable.Title >
          <Text style={styles.text}>Account</Text>
      </DataTable.Title>
      <DataTable.Title >
          <Text style={styles.text}>Code</Text>
      </DataTable.Title>
      <DataTable.Title >
           <Text style={styles.text}>Available Balance</Text> 
      </DataTable.Title>
   </DataTable.Header>
  {
   accounts.map(account=>{
     return(
        <DataTable.Row>
           <DataTable.Cell>{account.accNumber}</DataTable.Cell>
           <DataTable.Cell>{account.productCode}</DataTable.Cell>
           <DataTable.Cell>{account.availBalance}</DataTable.Cell>
        </DataTable.Row>
      )
   })}
 </DataTable>
```

Kindly suggest the way to display accounts data in tabular format supported by React Native. Is there any other way to map the data in table format apart from DataTable?

```
Expected Result:

Account                Code         Available Balance
56456454               1454541      987436.46
12424345645            154545641    500397.64
4554545664             44545        2467.02
```

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to know exactly is wrong without seeing the error message, but I was able to adapt your code to get the react-native-paper DataTable to work.

Below is a working example. You can also run it yourself [in this snack](https://snack.expo.io/@salus/datatable).

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { DataTable } from 'react-native-paper';

export default App = () => {
  var accounts = [
    {
      accNumber: '56456454',
      accType: 'D',
      productCode: '1454541',
      availBalance: '987436.46',
    },
    {
      accNumber: '12424345645',
      accType: 'D',
      productCode: '154545641',
      availBalance: '500397.64',
    },
    {
      accNumber: '4554545664',
      accType: 'D',
      productCode: '44545',
      availBalance: '2467.02',
    },
  ];

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <DataTable>
        <DataTable.Header>
          <DataTable.Title>Account</DataTable.Title>
          <DataTable.Title>Code</DataTable.Title>
          <DataTable.Title>
            Balance Available
          </DataTable.Title>
        </DataTable.Header>
        {
          accounts.map(account => {
          return (
            <DataTable.Row
              key={account.accNumber} // you need a unique key per item
              onPress={() => {
                // added to illustrate how you can make the row take the onPress event and do something
                console.log(`selected account ${account.accNumber}`)
              }}
            >
              <DataTable.Cell>
                {account.accNumber}
              </DataTable.Cell>
              <DataTable.Cell style={styles.messageColumn}>
                {account.productCode}
              </DataTable.Cell>
              <DataTable.Cell numeric>
                {account.availBalance}
              </DataTable.Cell>
            </DataTable.Row>
        )})}
      </DataTable>
    </View>
  );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are other ways to map data in react native using FlatList, etc.

Replace this section of your code:

```
{
   accounts.map(account=>{
     return(
        <DataTable.Row>
           <DataTable.Cell>{account.accNumber}</DataTable.Cell>
           <DataTable.Cell>{account.productCode}</DataTable.Cell>
           <DataTable.Cell>{account.availBalance}</DataTable.Cell>
        </DataTable.Row>
      )
   })}
 </DataTab
```

with this:

```
   { accounts.map((account, key)=>(
        <DataTable.Row>
            <DataTable.Cell>{account.accNumber}</DataTable.Cell>
            <DataTable.Cell>{account.productCode}</DataTable.Cell>
            <DataTable.Cell>{account.availBalance}</DataTable.Cell>
        </DataTable.Row>
        )
    )}
```

You should get rid of the warning.

Comment: For the above example i need to add pagination. Help me anyone. i am using react native expo

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on a project where I need to generate a table view from JSON. I am using FlatList of React-Native. Here is an example of my code

```
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <View style={[tableStyle.tableWrapper]}>
      <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true}>
        <FlatList
          data={[renderList]}
          renderItem={this.renderTableBody}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  </View>
```

you need to pass the renderList(an array generate from your JSON file) and render these value in renderItem.

Comment: as per my requirement, I have done the following:    
changed data={accounts}, renderItem={({item})=><Text style={styles.item}>{item.accNumber}{item.availBalance}{item.productCode}</Text>}  But still error is coming. Can u please elaborate the solution or any link to refer?

Comment: can you view the  ``renderTableBody`` how you write this?